# Как перенести результат работы pdfid в переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x

При попытке сделать вот так в интерпретаторе:

```
>>>x = os.system("pdfid New_book.pdf")  
PDFiD 0.2.1 New_cyberbook.pdf  
 PDF Header: %PDF-1.4  
 obj                 1502  
 endobj              1501  
 stream              1132  
 endstream           1132  
 xref                   1  
 trailer                1  
 startxref              1  
 /Page                 56  
 /Encrypt               0  
 /ObjStm                0  
 /JS                    0  
 /JavaScript            0  
 /AA                    0  
 /OpenAction            0  
 /AcroForm              0  
 /JBIG2Decode           0  
 /RichMedia             0  
 /Launch                0  
 /EmbeddedFile          0  
 /XFA                   0  
 /Colors > 2^24         0  

>>> x  
0
```

Как сделать так, что при вызове x выдавался сохранённый результат работы pdfid, а не 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Один самый распространенный, но не единственный из способов получить результат:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["pdfid","New_book.pdf"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

x = p.stdout.read().decode()
```

Первый аргумент это аргументы коммандной строки. shell=True запускает новую оболочку, можно без нее, но некоторые программы требуют. stdout=PIPE подключает буфер к выводу программы.

Comment: Интерпретатор начинает подвисать после введения p, а когда всё же добавляешь x, то появляется ошибка - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'.

Comment: Подвисать - это он ждет как программа завершится. Атрибут эррор - пайп наверное забыли включить. Если нет, то посмотрите код завершения